# Retrofit - Can I map response data fields?

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm testing/creating a REST client to the new Basecamp API using Retrofit. It looks something like this:

```
class Project {
  String name;
  String appUrl;
}

interface Basecamp {
    @GET("/projects.json")
    List<Project> projects();
}
```

In the json response, the source field for `appUrl` is called `app_url`. Asides from renaming the field in the class, is there a simple way to map the response data with my data structure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I found the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007149/simple-custom-mapping-of-json-property-to-object-property-with-retrofit). Turns out this can be solved using Gson:

```
class Project {
  String name;

  @SerializedName("app_url")
  String appUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Jackson for JSON parsing with Retrofit you can use the @JsonProperty annotation:

Example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties (ignoreUnknown = true)
    class Project {
      @JsonProperty("name")
      String name;
      @JsonProperty("app_url")
      String appUrl;
    }
```